# How to distinguish orders by shopify market?

Tags: shopify

We are planning to introduce Markets in our Shopify store (3, for the start).

So far we were consuming Shopify Orders via webhooks in our own application.

I do not see a 'market' field in the Orders webhook JSON or anything similar that could point to the Market where the order is coming from.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Milan

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?